# como separar codigo en eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Supongamos que tengo main.java  y code.java

en el ide  processing se puede abrir una pestaña y escribir una funcion para despues usalo dentro de draw()

intente hacer en eclipse algo como esto

en main.java tengo

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        print_hello();
    }

}
```

en code.java tengo

```
void print_hello()
{

        System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
```

pero me tira errores

como abro una pestaña vacia para  seguir programando pero que pertenesca a main.java

quiero hacer esto para  programas de muchas linias de codigo

Comment: Podrias crear una clase Hello_world

Comment: Java no es php, ¿como vas a llamar a print_hello si no has creado el objeto Code.java? Ademas los nombres de tus archivos deben empezar con mayuscula.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el modificador static en el método print_hello, ya que pertecenería a la clase, y no a un objeto:

```
public class Code {

    public static void print_hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world");
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Code.print_hello();

    }

}
```

Salida:

> hello, world

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar los [static methods](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-static-method-program) y asi te evitas instanciar objetos pero recuerda **java es orientado a objetos** por lo tanto si planeas escribir mucho codigo seria bueno utilizaras este paradigma y dejaras a los static methods a tareas muy concretas.

Un ejemplo es la clase [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) que ejemplifica una clase la cual soporta un determindado numero de subrutinas  o metodos la cual no necesitan ser instanciada para poder ser utilizada.

Saludos....